# calculate the curvature of a surface with a Lambert quadrilateral

Tags: hyperbolic-geometry

I was wondering how can I calculate the curvature of a surface?

For example:

Given a Lambert quadrilateral ABCD (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_quadrilateral )
with: $ DA \bot AB $, $ AB \bot BC $, $ BC \bot CD $ and we know the length of each segment (but not the  $\angle ADC $ )

Can I calculate the curvature of the plane? (and how!)

Or do I also need to know $\angle ADC $?

Do I even have to know all four lengths, can I do it with 3?

Answer (score 1):

If the segments are geodesics in your surface, then the Gauss Bonnet Theorem will tell you that (letting $Q$ denote the quadrilateral and $K$ the (Gaussian) curvature of the surface)
$$\iint_Q K\,dA = \sum_{j=1}^4 \iota_j - 2\pi,$$
where $\iota_j$, $j=1,\dots,4$, are the interior angles. In your case, you'll have $\iota_4-\pi/2$ for that right-hand side. That is, if the fourth angle is a right angle for all such possible quadrilaterals, $K=0$, as in Euclidean space. (In particular, the lengths of the sides are irrelevant.)

If $K$ is not constant, you would have to take limits as your quadrilateral shrinks down to a particular point $p$, and you would have
$$K(p) = \lim_{\Delta A\to 0} \frac1{\Delta A}\iint K dA = \lim_{\Delta A\to 0} \frac1{\Delta A}(\iota_4-\pi/2).$$

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Yes the segments are (parts of) geodesics, and the curvature is constant (and negative), but I cannot understand that the length of the segments has no influence on the calculation, a simple construction for example in the Poincare disk model shows otherwise. In a hyperbolic plane the $\angle D $ grows to a right angle if the segments lengths decreases, maybe $\angle D $ is dependent on the area of the quadrilateral but this is (partly) dependent on the length of the segments

Comment: In hyperbolic geometry you have angle-angle-angle congruence of triangles (because of Gauss-Bonnet), so angles really do determine everything!! You're too used to Euclidean.